# Is there a way for a rundeck non-privileged user to change their own password?

Tags: rundeck

All I see are the sections in /etc/rundeck/realm.properties but nothing in the GUI which would empower the user to change their own password...

Thanks ahead.

P.S. Didn't see anything with Google about it either...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that on GUI yet, only editing the `realm.properties` file. But the best (and secure) way to manage users is getting them from [LDAP](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap) / [Active Directory](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#active-directory) and manage their properties from LDAP / Active Directory.